# Redirect to URL with gathering information in socials

Tags: php, facebook, redirect, social-networking, url-shortener

I am trying to write my own shorten URL service for my website.
Everything is OK and redirecting works, but when I use the shortened URL on Facebook, Twitter or other social media the site cannot gather page title or other page information, while for other shorten URL services like `goo.gl` Facebook and other social networks can gather more information for that link.

My php code is:

```
<?php
...
    header("HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently");
    header("Location: ".$link);
    exit;
...
?>
```

What is the problem?

Comment: When you post a link to FB, it takes a second for it to gather the information. It does that by accessing the link destination. So, have you confirmed that when you post your shortened link to FB, your web server receives a corresponding request for the proper page?

Comment: Yes, the link is alive and when I enter this link in address bar my page will redirect to orginal url, but in FB after some seconds loading, will show page not found !

Comment: Also, you might want to try sending a "302 Found" redirect instead of 301.

Comment: @ElmerCat Thanks, I changed the header to "HTTP/1 302 Found" but not work :(

Comment: Now, to be sure, when you use the full URL in FB, it does gather the title and image, etc. as expected?  So then, how does is your shortened URL service work — in other words, can it supply the requested content directly, rather than issuing a redirect? It could be, that FB doesn't want to trust a redirected URL for the purpose of gathering the preview information.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the docs at

- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/webmasters/crawler

to get some details on how to handle redirects with FB...